# How to interpret SZ and RSS values

Tags: solaris

I am running a ps command on solaris to get SZ and RSS values, here is the sample output

```
USER-PID-%CPU-%MEM-SZ-RSS-TT-S-START-

root-3-0.1-0.0-0-0-?-S-Feb-
qacom2-7440-0.0-0.0-3912-3344-pts/7-O-13:25:22-
root-6589-0.0-0.15985621000-?-S-Feb-08-1309:34-
```

If you see this outpuit, for PID 6589, SZ is '?' and RSS is 'S' what exactly this indicates?

Answer (score 1):

To me, it looks like this:

```
SZ      RSS
0       0
3912    3344
59856   21000
```

The question marks indicate that the process is not attached to a terminal. The "S" indicates that the process is in the Sleep state. The "O" indicates that the process is running.

Why is your `ps` output formatted that way?

Comment: I have formatted that way because numbers overlapping, for example %MEM is value is big coming under SZ.. For line 3, I read SZ as '?' and RSS as 'S'. I think 0.15985621000 is belongs to %MEM. If you see hypens(-) carefully you will see this difference.

Comment: @goutham: I disagree. I think your fields are getting truncated and are being "overlapped" somehow.

Comment: I think you are right. Is there anyway I can get SZ and RSS values without overlapping? I am running command "/usr/ucb/ps auxww"

Comment: @goutham: When I run `/usr/ucb/ps auxwww` on Solaris 5.10, I get nice, clean columns without overlapping. You must be doing something that causes the overlapping and puts those hyphens where there should be multiple spaces. What is the *complete* command you're using or how have you got your environment set up that might cause this?